# Is it possible to run an onclick javascript function inside another javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, dom-events

Currently learning javascript and was curious about this possibility.
I have this code inside a .JS file

```
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
                    x.setAttribute("src", "helpimage.png");
                    x.setAttribute("width", "20");
                    x.setAttribute("height", "20");
                      x.setAttribute("alt", "help image");
                      x.setAttribute("id","image");
                    var row = document.createElement('div');
                    row.classList.add('row');
                    var label = document.createElement('div');
                        label.id = machineName + '-label';
                        label.classList.add('col-md-5');
                        label.innerHTML = humanName + ':';
                        label.appendChild(x);
                        label.onclick = function() {myFunction()};
                        
                    row.appendChild(label);
```

and this function titled "MyFunction"

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById(machineName + '-label').innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
  }
```

What this code does is that first a function is called which creates a simple form element with a label. I attach a picture labeled "x" into the label.
I would like to be able to click that label, with an onclick event, and then change it to whatever I want. (just testing here)

So once my first function generates my form, I then want to click my label and have it change to "YOU CLICKED ME".

Except when I click the picture nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

picture of what I want to click. [image]

Comment: can you check the console to see if you get any errors?

Comment: wow so sorry, nice catch. i was doing some other testing and accidentally put machine name when i should have put image as the ID

Comment: Are you trying to change the text of the label?  Then you need to include `+ '-label'` in the ID when calling `getElementById`

Comment: ah i haven't learned how to check consoles for errors yet, I'll look that up and see what I can find.

Comment: @Barmar I'm hoping that I can click my image and then have it change to "YOU CLICKED ME". it's nonsense but I was hoping to do some quick testing and this seemed so straightforward but when I click my image, it doesn't change

Comment: Do you mean `document.getElementById("image")`?

Comment: Setting the `innerHTML` of an `<img>` element doesn't do anything. Images are not text containers.

Comment: @barmar ah another typo.  yep! I'll fix that. 
but it still doesn't work with "image"

Comment: ohhhhh so I can't just switch text out with an image? welp. that answers that. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the text that you want to replace in another nested element, rather than in the element that also contains the image.

```js
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
x.setAttribute("src", "helpimage.png");
x.setAttribute("width", "20");
x.setAttribute("height", "20");
x.setAttribute("alt", "help image");
x.setAttribute("id", "image");
var row = document.createElement('div');
row.classList.add('row');
var label = document.createElement('div');
let machineName = "filename";
label.id = machineName + '-label';
label.classList.add('col-md-5');
let humanName = "File Name";
let text = document.createElement("span");
text.id = machineName + "-text";
text.innerHTML = humanName + ':';
label.appendChild(text);
label.appendChild(x);
label.onclick = function() {
  myFunction()
};

row.appendChild(label);
document.body.appendChild(row);

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById(machineName + '-text').innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}
```

Comment: oh cool, I will try that. thank you!

Comment: hmm it still isn't working. Question.. since I appended child element that is a picture into a plaintext element, does that break anything? 
I also changed it so now I don't click the picture but the name itself.I also included a picture of the thing I'm clicking

Comment: Don't change the question to match my answer. Now no one can see what I was fixing.

Comment: You want to change `File Name` but keep the image?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: eh at this point I just want filename to change when I click it. the image appended to it can change to but I'd like to get it working. 
i'll try removing the appended image and doing what you told me with the DIV on label. 
maybe something will change

Comment: your suggestion is fantastic but I figured out why it wasn't working on my end. the machinename variable was allocated correctly so when it tried to call the ID, it found nothing. Thank you for your help!